# Map Cloud storage and Cloud run to same domain to avoid CORS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-dns

Here we made a simple website using cloud storage and a cloud run as an API .
have used manage custom domain for domain mapping .
When connected using javascript ,we run into CORS error .

Is there any possibility to map both with cloud storage and the cloud run API as the same domain  using cloud DNS perhaps ?

So, the DNS records currently are:

example.com CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.

we want :

example.com/service pointing to the cloud run custom domain.

I tried with URI redirect but it won't help as again we are getting CORS error.

Thanks

Comment: Soon, you will be able to put a loadbalancer in front of these 2 resources, and thus having only 1 IP/DNS name for all. Stay tuned.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  Alright ! For the time being can you suggest any method which could solve this issue ,for the time being or by using 3rd pary DNS like cloudflare ?

Comment: @Kaustubh, Technically it's impossible to have different DNS records based on the URL –that's just not how DNS works, DNS doesn't know anything about URLs or HTTP. :)

Comment: For the time being, you could configure CORS in your Cloud Run API to accept requests from your domain example.com

Comment: @JoseV exactly done , now it's working but I have used this middleware https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/ ,the google docs with recommends to add header was not working as expected.